# How to calculate frequency per groups in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I want to create a barplot showing the frequencies that each age appears on the table. (Each Id represents a person)

I was expecting to get the frequency by adding count but it doesn't work

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: at least post a image/screenshot of what you have done so far